# How can I check a variables value constantly without using setInterval?

Tags: javascript

I am building a incremental game. I have a progress bar that fills up 1 point every second.. And when that bar reaches 10 points it resets back to 0..

The problem I am having is checking if the variable is 10 at all times. I am currently using setInterval to run the function every 10 milliseconds but I feel like this is not good for the website.

I have been trying to find a solution for this for months, can someone please help me out here..

In short: How do I check a variables value at all times without causing lag/inefficiency

Comment: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you should probably be using `requestAnimationFrame` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Variables only change when you change them.

Comment: [I downvoted because - no code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: If you need to do something (increase a point) **every second** than why would you ever want to run an expensive setInterval **every 10 ms**? Btw... just to remind you that 60FPS = 1000 / 60 = ~16.6ms - Don't you think 10ms is just over exaggerating?

Answer (score 2):

So, to recap, you're running a `setInterval` at 10ms which task is just to check if the value of some variable equals `10`. There's so many solutions, but hard to answer specifically without seeing any code.

***Solution 1:*** Call a desired function immediately after where you increment your variable

```js
const doTheMagic = (points) => {
  console.log(`You reached score: ${points}`)
};

let points = 0; // Start at 0 

const incrementPoint = () => {
  points += 1;
  if (points === 10) doTheMagic(points);
  points %= 10; // Loop-back points to 0 when reaches 10
};

// You say you increment `points` at intervals of ~1000ms:
setInterval(incrementPoint, 1000);
```

```html
Wait 10s... Then again 10s... etc...
```

***Solution 2:*** [Use setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)
***Solution 3:*** [Use Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: This is perhaps the most helpful answer possible given the lack of code and information in the question. +1